# What preposition to use when saying "drawn in accordance with the ISO standard"

Tags: prepositions

Here's the relevant part of the sentence I'm struggling with:

> "... as well as not being drawn by/to/? the ISO standard."

I guess one could write "... as well as not being drawn in accordance with/to the ISO standard."

Still not sure if one should use "with" or "to" in that case either. Problem with that sentence is that it is unnecessarily long. I have a feeling that there is a preposition one can use without having to write "in accordance with/to", though I may be wrong.

Comment: "... as well as not [**conforming**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/conform) to the ISO standard."

Comment: @WeatherVane very good alternative, might just use it :)